# 3 phase AC motor wont start after overloading

Tags: motor, ac

A 3 phase induction motor is stuck with a heavy load and was making hum noise. After it is unloaded it still wont start. Any ideas where to start trouble-shooting? Would overloading activate the circuit breakers in an AC motor?

Comment: Check resistance of all phases. If one is different from the others ... problem.

Comment: Check incoming power? An overload condition should trip something somewhere...

Comment: @BrianDrummond Do you mean the resistances of stator windings?

Comment: What other resistances could I mean? Also, it turns by hand without much friction, right?

Comment: you re right just wanted to be sure

Comment: Is your motor equipped with an overload protection as the  NEMA Standard MG-1 specifies : https://law.resource.org/pub/us/cfr/ibr/005/nema.mg-1.2009.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical AC motor is a bunch of (very) cleverly-wound coils to create magnetic fields in the right sequence to make it spin. If there's humming, there's current flow. If the shaft isn't turning, either there's a substantial mechanical load (check if you can turn the shaft manually) or the magnetic fields aren't being set up properly. The latter means either your supply is incorrect in some fashion, or the motor is damaged. I'd check the resistance of the windings, and the resistance from each winding to the chassis. You could also hi-pot test from winding to chassis, but only if you have the spec of what it's supposed to be.

Comment: Please note for novices or inexperienced people: Never touch the shaft of a motor unless the motor is positively de-energized. If it should start to spin while you are in contact with it, you can become seriously injured. I am sure Stephen knows this, and the OP probably knows this, but many people may read this answer who don't know that. This is not a criticism of the answer.